# Store PayPal not working

Tags: add-on, expresso-store

Latest EE and Latest Store.

I've setup PayPal Express in settings and have `{exp:store:checkout payment_method="paypal_express"}` on the final checkout page. I have the submit button as `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Your Order">`. When I click the button nothing happens. I was expecting to be whisked over to PayPal. Any ideas what I've missed?

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Could you include the relevant template markup in your question (or upload it as a [gist](https://gist.github.com))? Does literally nothing happen or does the form submit and reload the current page?

Comment: I hadn't collected the buyer email address and so the page wasn't submitting.

Comment: PayPal requires an email address to work properly. From the sounds of it you have inline_error handling turned on but have not added `{error:field_name}` to your templates which would of helped you in trackdown the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Justin mentioned in the comments, it sounds like there are some errors on your page which you haven't templated.

As a first step, always remove `error_handling="inline"` from your checkout tag, to see all the errors.

In the comments you mentioned it was missing the email address, so that sounds like the problem. All orders require an email address (that the order confirmation email is sent to), and at this stage it can't be automatically pulled from the customer's Paypal account, it must be collected before you redirect the customer for payment.